# Splitting line layer using another point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, vector, line, splitting

How to split a line layer using another point layer in QGIS?

I have one point layer and one line layer. I want to split the line layer between two points (those two points belongs to point layer) using QGIS. how can I perform this splitting using QGIS?

I used `v.split` for splitting the line layer, but I am not getting any output.

Comment: I don't think you can split lines based on points unless the points overlap the lines, if you want to split lines between two points that are not overlapping the line, you can try to convert your points to a line first ( make a line using the points you want to split the original line with) and use that to split your lines.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 18):

There is the SAGA's ["Split Lines at Points"](http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.6/shapes_lines_8.html) module (search in the Processing Toolbox <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: `QGIS Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Vector line tools`)

[image]

In the above example all my points are within 2.8 m (or 2.9 m) from those white lines. Setting `Epsilon` to `3.0` covers these gaps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just added the algorithm "**Split Lines At Nearest Points By Condition**" to [ProcessX Plug-In](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ProcessX/). It can also handle Multilines, Z and M values, but only gives good results in projected CRS'. You can also use a maximum distance to points or two optional expression/attribute conditions to find matching points.

[image]

*Disclaimer: I am the author of the Plug-In. I tried to explain the used method of this algorithm [in this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/473795/107424).*

Answer (score -3):

A practical non programming answer is to make a buffer of the points you want to use. Then cut them into the lines so that you run a snap process knowing the threshold you have to use from the previous buffer.

Comment: this will produce multiple cuts.